# How to call a file with inode?

Tags: unix

How can I open a file with its inode? I mean, lets fileName has 123456 inode. I want to open fileName like $cd fileName. How can I do this using its inode?

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal way to open an inode. You should always open it via a link, i.e. the filename.